# Better English pronunciation shell?

Tags: directory, audio

Can some one recommend an English world pronunciation dictionary in terminal environment and sounds better than the default "say" ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/501910/how-to-text-to-speech-output-using-command-line

Comment: @steve seems all of them are using the synthetic pronunciation, would be nice to have one directly talk to google translate or www.dictionary.com to get the pronunciation